# Why is this bootstrap popover not working the way it should

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why is this bootstrap popover not working the way it should?

```
<section id='popOver'>
   <figure>
      <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="popoverBtn" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content='Somne content insdie Popover'>Popover</button>
      <figcaption>Bootstrap Popover</figcaption>
   </figure>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Comment: do you have any console errors?

Comment: no it doesnt show any errors

Comment: check ur page source and make sure the javascript is loading too, other than that i cant find anything

Comment: If we place the code you provided her in Bootply it functions as expected. Check your code to ensure you're linking to jQuery and Bootstrap's JS properly.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it either... please include a [mcve] to your question. Welcome to StackOverflow